# MySQL Delete rows from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables users and pd having a common column i_uid

For deleting from both the tables a single row having i_uid of 1010 I issued the following statement using mysqli::query in php script

```
DELETE 
FROM `users`,`pd`
WHERE `users`.`i_uid`=`pd`.`i_uid` AND `users`.`i_uid` = 1010;
```

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Does it work when you try?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

since you are deleting rows from multiple table, the only missing is to specify on what tables the row will be deleted,

```
DELETE `users`,`pd`
FROM `users`, `pd`
WHERE `users`.`i_uid`=`pd`.`i_uid` AND `users`.`i_uid` = 1010;
```

in the query above, it will delete rows from both tables. I suggest to change statement using ANSI join like below,

```
DELETE  a, b 
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN pd b
            ON a.i_uid = b.i_uid
WHERE  a.i_uid = 1010
```

if you want to delete from `users` table,

```
DELETE  a
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN pd b
            ON a.i_uid = b.i_uid
WHERE  a.i_uid = 1010
```

Comment: thanx for help....can you explain me the join syntax...normally i used to specify column names before FROM....

Comment: that's the source table where te rows will be deleted. it is necessary since your query involves multiple table.

Comment: aren't we specifying those tables after FROM? so why again before it?

Comment: the table **before** the `FROM` clause are where the records will be deleted. the table **after** the `FROM` clause are where the records will be search. but it is optional if you are deleting in one table only

Comment: It's not working for me. Here is my query : `delete p, pc, l, c from posts p inner join post_content pc on p.post_id=pc.post_id inner join likes l on p.post_id=l.post_id  inner join comments c on c.post_id=p.post_id where p.post_id=406;`

Answer (score 2):

Use `Left Join` and specify the tables on which corresponding rows will be deleted.

```
DELETE users, pd
FROM users, pd
LEFT JOIN pd
ON pd.i_uid = users.i_uid
WHERE users.i_uid = 1010
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are correct but since no one mentioned it I will. You could use **InnoDB** engine and specify foreign keys and **DELETE ON CASCADE**. So that each time you delete a user it will delete all referencing rows from different tables.

Read up on **Foreign Keys** and DELETE ON CASCADE

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple I suggest using just two queries:

```
DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `i_uid` = 1010;
DELETE FROM `pd` WHERE `i_uid` = 1010;
```